# How do I get the caller name in Asterisk using Python?

Tags: python, asterisk

I have an Asterisk (Elastix) installation. I have a MySQL database with about 10,000 customer names and numbers. I would like my call agent to recognize the name associated with the number. I can have the data available in any format json, memcached, SQL whatever. We have build the custom CRM using Python. I tried pyst to interface with Asterisk, but no progress. Is there a way to parse some log file, database to generate the caller ID or number real time in Asterisk...

What we would like is the fastest way in which the call agent able to recohnize the customer calling in based on the number he or she is calling from.

Answer (score 0):

You can check cdr data in cdr table(after end of call)

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+mysql

You can control asterisk call flow using AGI

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI

if you use agi, you can get callerid id by issue

```
GET_FULL_VARIABLE CALLERID(num)
```